# (Ajax & express js) Express js authorize middleware

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have a simple middleware of authorize in my app. It works perfectly in both GET and POST normal requests but when i make a POST request via ajax, It doesn't redirect to a page 401 instead it ignores the middleware and continues to my model and insert data into the db.

Code:

```
function(req, res, next){
        if(!req.session.user){
            res.status(401);
            res.redirect('/401');
        }
        next(); }
```

Can someone explain me why this middleware isn't working if it is an ajax request but working correctly with normal requests?

Comment: Did you try putting `next()` within an `else` clause or at least put a `return;` right after `res.redirect('/401')` so that execution stops before hitting `next()`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. putting a return; after res.redirect(); works for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that even though you are sending a redirect, the *javascript* code execution continues because `next()` is not inside an `else` clause. So putting a `return` right after `res.redirect('/401')` or putting `next()` inside an `else` will avoid the problem.